# PHP model class for MVC-based project

Tags: php, join, model

Is there a good existing PHP model class or library, which can be used in a small MVC framework as the "finder" for models?

We are trying to build a very lightweight framework for a specific site, instead of using the larger ones with a ton of extreme functionality. The most important thing is some smart way of querieng the database - including relations, like you can do with models in for example CakePHP or Yii framework.

class User extends Model

Now I can do something like User::find(), or user $user->getItems() where items is a predefined related model with some kind of settings (hasOne, hasMany etc.), maybe even with join instructions.

I think reinventing the wheel is bad, but I don't want to get into a large framework only for the model's finder method.

Comment: Take a look at [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PHP-activercord

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

> php-activerecord is an open source ORM library based on the ActiveRecord pattern. It aims to massively simplify the interactions with your database and eliminate the chore of hand written SQL for common operations. Unlike other ORMs, you do not need to use any code generators nor maintain mapping files for your tables. This library was inspired by Ruby on Rails' implementation and therefore borrows many of its conventions and ideas.

It´s easy to implement and more easy work with this library. It´s well documented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for an ORM. Take a look at how [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm) have done it, they use the ActiveRecord pattern. This has worked well for me in the past.